# Convert JavaScript Regex String to PHP Regex String

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have JavaScript regex string and want to convert it to php regex.

Here is the string for JavaScript:

```
/(937(?:00\d{6}|[789]\d{7}
```

This validate phone numbers. Acceptable format of phone numbers are:

93700600708
93785657024
93795657024

93 is country code and 700, 78 and 79 are the network code followed by 7 digits.

Comment: Who's stopping you? I don't see a question here.

Comment: Your regex has unclosed parentheses.

Comment: http://php.net/preg_match - for your stated purposes, this should work.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are not language specific. They are applicable in most coding languages and used the same way -- the only difference is how they are applied. For PHP, use methods such as [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match) or [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

For more information on Regular Expressions, go [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). If you go to Languages and Libraries, you can see all the coding languages that support Regular Expressions. Some may require libraries or packages, but in general the way you write regular expressions is fairly universal.

EDIT: I stand corrected as there are some very slight variations between different coding languages for how they handle Regex. You can find out how to make Regular Expressions for PHP here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.introduction.php

You can also get more information on some of the subtle differences in general [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

Comment: There certainly are language-specific differences  in regular expressions.

Comment: @CrazyTrain thanks for the correction. Updated my answer. Most of the time when I've used Regex, I didn't have to change anything ><...

Answer (score 1):

if we make your JS RegExp valid to use as an example, you can see how JSON converts JS literals to PHP literals, so far as the commonly-supported RegExps syntax subsets are concerned:

```
var rx=/(937(?:00\d{6}|[789]\d{7}))/ ;
var php= JSON.stringify( rx + '');
alert( php ); // shows : "/(937(?:00\\d{6}|[789]\\d{7}))/"
```